# Jquery weekly planner

Tags: jquery, uislider

I want to create a weekly schedule planner.
I have found on the net a widget that does half of what I need.
The widget, plus minor modifications can be found here: http://jsfiddle.net/inadcod/GyanJ/
My problem is that for each individual day, I would like to be able to add new time interval sliders to capture different hour intervals for a single day. Something like for Monday I would like to set three intervals, one between 8:00 and 12:00, another between 12:45 and 16:30, and yet another between 17:00 and 21:45.
If anyone can help me I would really appreciate it. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$('.addNewInterval').click
```

You forgot the . for the class! Add the interval slider relative to `$(this)` inside the button click handler now you will add it everywhere.

Add youre new configuration inside the new `.slider()` function. Also mind that I'm only selecting the new one and not all sliders (using the class reference like you did).

http://jsfiddle.net/GyanJ/5/

***Edit***

You will have to insert new input fields to populate. (or you will override) And you can fetch the value afterwards but it is always 0 at the point you where trying. Better is when the value changes inside the slide handler.

It may be wise to put the configuration/options object into a variable so you can use it not only when first created but also for every extra added slider rather then writing twice the same code.

this might help, I added some comments.

http://jsfiddle.net/GyanJ/8/

***Edit***

done a little more work on it: (might need some styling)

http://jsfiddle.net/GyanJ/16/

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. I modified the example as seen here: http://jsfiddle.net/inadcod/GyanJ/. Now it creates a range slider, and all I have to do now is to capture the intervals of the second, third, etc sliders next to the values of the first slider, and set the second and following sliders to have a start value no lower than the highest value of the first slider.

Comment: Well The idea is to select the new slider, or sliders, if more are created. Now I have tried to capture the time interval of the new sliders but I didn't manage. Ex http://jsfiddle.net/inadcod/GyanJ/

Comment: I have updated the fiddle yet again: http://jsfiddle.net/inadcod/GyanJ/. I can now get the values for the new sliders, but as you said in your comment the values are entered for each day, and I don't know how to create independent inputs for these values. Can you have a look please?

Comment: I reached to this point http://jsfiddle.net/inadcod/GyanJ/13/ and again I got stuck :(

Comment: ha! and still there is another issue I cannot solve. I would like the sliders for a single day to be dependent one of the other. I mean if I choose the interval 8:00 - 13:00 for a slider, the other sliders wouldn't be allowed to enter that interval. Is this possible?

Comment: yes but thats a little more work... I can give you a start.. http://jsfiddle.net/Vandeplas/GyanJ/19/ but I guess I selected wrong first/last markers (the one is on top of the other use tab and arrows to move them) also still have to set the initial positions. But I have not to much time now... I hope I helped you on you're way

Comment: Yes. Thanks a lot. Hope I'll manage to make it work for the third and so forth sliders as-well. Thanks again.

Comment: Well I've tried to see why the third slider and so forth don't work, but it's too much for me; I couldn't even figure out why if I set the first slider to a value, and the second to another, after that I cannot change the first max value anymore. I believe it has something to do with refreshing the values for the sliders, but it's too complicated for my knowledge.

Comment: What I managed to do is this http://jsfiddle.net/inadcod/GyanJ/20/. I made the "addNewInterval" button disappear after it is clicked once, so the user has only 2 ranges per day (not what I wanted, but I donno how to set the rest of the range sliders to work). Also I included a reset button, but unfortunately it resets the entire thing, I mean each day, when clicked :(

Comment: yet a little more working :) http://jsfiddle.net/Vandeplas/GyanJ/23/ I hope you're not surprised by the reset button resetting everything.. you're reloading the page :s instaid remove the objects... I suggest ready a little more about javascript and jQuery... and take a close look at the documentation of jquery and jqueryUI it 'll get you quickly on your way.